# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can sums of this type be split up like that? Or can they only be rewritten as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most certainly not. That's not even true for finite sums, for example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^3 \frac1n \sum_{n=1}^3 \frac 1n = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac16 \neq \frac{49}{36} = \sum_{n=1}^3\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Sums cannot be split up like that. What you're probably thinking is:

$$\sum_l \sum_m \sum_n \frac{1}{lmn} = \sum_l \frac{1}{l} \sum_m \frac{1}{m} \sum_n \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sums don't work this way.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac 1m=\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty\frac 1{nm}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n<m}\frac2{nm}.$$